# Session with prepared statement

Tags: php

After i login with the $_SESSION["user_id"]; into the second page is this the correct way or sequence for using prepared statement like the bind_result to the stmt_fetch redeclare??

here is session.php

```
session_start();
require './database.php';

$idec = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT user_id, name, username, password, age, 
user_type, gender FROM user WHERE user_id=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $idec);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $idz, $namesz, $usernamesz, $passwordsz, 
$agez, $user_typesz, $gendersz);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0){
while($rows = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
   $idec = $idz;
   $names = $namesz;
   $usernames = $usernamesz;
   $passwords = $passwordsz;
   $ages = $agez;
   $user_types = $user_typesz;
   $genders = $gendersz;
}
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
if(!isset($idec)){
    header("Location: index.php");
} 

mysqli_close($conn);
```

here is my secondpage.php

```
<?php  require "session.php" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $usernames?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do i need re assign bind result to stmt_fetch

Comment: $idec in $_SESSION["user_id"] and then bind_para is $idec but in bind_result it is okay to put another variable $idz to assign as $idec in fetch?